# Keep date and timestamp when converting from PostgreSQL/PostGIS to Esri File-Geodatabase using Spatialite

Tags: postgis, arcmap, file-geodatabase, spatialite

I use ogr2ogr to export geodata from PostGIS to SpatiaLite like follows:

```
ogr2ogr -f SQLite -dsco SPATIALITE=yes C:/target.sqlite PG:"connectionstring" -sql "select * from blabla"
```

If I do so and open the SQLite file with ArcMap the date and timestamp columns are displayed as double and will only contain the year.  So far I created a string column containing the date which I use later to recalculate the date. But is there a better way to read SQLite date and timestamp columns with ArcMap?

I initially thought the problem is based on the conversion from PostGIS to SpatiaLite. Opening the same SQLite file in QGIS showed date and timestamp columns as expected.

Using GDAL 3.1.4 / PostgreSQL 12 / Windows 64 / ArcMap 10.2

Comment: Test if dates and datetimes convert right if you use GeoPackage instead of SpatiaLite to confirm that the PostGIS side is OK.

Comment: @BERA Explicit type casting did make no difference.

Comment: @user30184 I was able to convert date and timestamp columns to GeoPackage.

Comment: I just got it. It is not a problem of ogr2ogr, it is arcmap not wanting to read the date column properly.

Comment: Dates and times in SQLite tend to be complicated https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html and applications often have problems with interpreting right what the other party was meaning. GeoPackage standard defines almost explicitly how datetimes must be stored.